# Как в TypeScript определить тип ключей и строго определить число и названия свойств в интерфейсе?

Tags: typescript, интерфейс

Сталкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
interface dateAccessories {
  day: number | string;
  month: number | string;
  year: number | string;
  hours: number | string;
  minutes: number | string;
}
```

И такая функция, где этот интерфейс используется:

```
export default function timeFormating(dateStr: string): timeCreation {
  const dateObj: Date = new Date(dateStr);

  const dateAccessories: dateAccessories = {
    day: dateObj.getDate(),
    month: dateObj.getMonth() + 1,
    year: dateObj.getFullYear(),
    hours: dateObj.getHours(),
    minutes: dateObj.getMinutes(),
  }

  for (let accessory in dateAccessories) {
    let value = dateAccessories[accessory];

    if (value < 10) {
      dateAccessories[accessory] = `0${value}`;
    }
  }

  return {
    date: `${dateAccessories.day}.${dateAccessories.month}.${dateAccessories.year}`,
    time: `${dateAccessories.hours}:${dateAccessories.minutes}`
  }
}
```

В цикле, а имено в строке `let value = dateAccessories[accessory];` ts ругается:

> Элемент неявно имеет тип "any", так как выражение типа "string" не
> может использоваться для индексации типа "dateAccessories".   В типе
> "dateAccessories" не обнаружена сигнатура индекса с параметром типа
> "string".ts(7053)

Я полистал доку и нашёл способ вылечить это вот так:

```
interface dateAccessories {
  [key: string]: string | number;
  day: number | string;
  month: number | string;
  year: number | string;
  hours: number | string;
  minutes: number | string;
}
```

Но в этом случае интерефейс `dateAccessories` перестаёт быть ограниченым, т.е. в объект этого интерфейса можно добавлять любые свойства, и ts не будет ругатся, если туда ещё что-нибудь попадёт, главное чтобы указаные свойства присутствовали.

Подскажите, как надо написать интерфейс, чтобы тип его ключей был опредёл, и чтобы он был строго ограничен конкретными свойствами, которые должны в него попасть, не больше не меньше?

Comment: можно в конкретных местах сделать кастинг `let value = dateAccessories[accessory as keyof dateAccessories];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Актуально для текущей версии TS 4.6.1

Здравствуйте! Проблема не в вашем интерфейсе, а в том, что typescript в конструкции цикла `for...in`, обходя ключи объекта `dateAccessories` не определяет их как `key of` данного объекта и считает просто `string`. Как вы понимаете, с точки зрения TS, просто строка не может подойти как ключ для объекта, т.к. это может привести к потенциальным ошибкам. Ключом может послужить только конкретная строка

Подобная проблема справедлива так же и для альтернативы итерации по ключам объекта в виде `Object.keys`

Самым простым решением будет указать явно для TS, что переменная `accessory` является именно одним из ключей `dateAccessories` интерфейса

```
for (let accessory in dateAccessories) {
  let value = dateAccessories[accessory as keyof dateAccessories];
}
```

В случае если вы решите переписать цикл с использованием `Object.keys`, то явный каст может выглядеть вот таким образом:

```
(Object.keys(dateAccessories) as Array<keyof typeof dateAccessories>).map(key => dateAccessories[key])
```

Решение с `Object.keys` можно улучшить, создав типизированную версию данной функции вот таким способом:

```
declare global {
    interface ObjectConstructor {
        typedKeys<T>(obj: T): Array<keyof T>
    }
}
Object.typedKeys = Object.keys as any

/** Теперь можно получать ключи без явного приведения к типу каждый раз */
Object.typedKeys(dateAccessories).map(key => dateAccessories[key])
```

Или пропатчив уже существующую вот таким способом

```
type ObjectKeys<T> = T extends object
    ? (keyof T)[]                    
    : T extends number               
    ? []                             
    : T extends Array<any> | string  
    ? string[]                       
    : never;                         
                                     
interface ObjectConstructor {        
    keys<T>(o: T): ObjectKeys<T>;    
}                                    


/** Обращаемся к уже улучшенной в плане типизации версии */
Object.keys(dateAccessories).map(key => dateAccessories[key])
```